# Increment ROW, not COLUMN when dragging formula horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to drag the formula

```
=if(and(AHTpivot!$A1=statusSheet!$A1, AHTpivot!$B1="wrap-up"),AHTpivot!$C1, "")
```

right to adjacent columns about 1,000 times. I only want `statusSheet!$A1` to increase, and it needs to increase in rows instead of columns.

For instance, if the formula is in `A1`, and I drag it to `B1`, it should be in cell `B2`. [?]

```
=if(and(AHTpivot!$A1=statusSheet!$A2, AHTpivot!$B1="wrap-up"),AHTpivot!$C1, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=if(and(AHTPivot!$A1=indirect("StatusSheet!$A"&Column()),AHTPivot!$B1="wrap-up"),AHTPivot!$C1, "")
```

Comment: @driggers if this answer helps you I think you should vote it up instead of "thank you"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an array formula if you don't want to drag the formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(

(AHTpivot!$A1=INDIRECT("statusSheet!$A"&COLUMN(A1:AAA1))
* (AHTpivot!$B1="wrap-up")

,AHTpivot!$C1, "")
```

*The ***** acts as an **and***.

Change `AAA1` to the column reference you desire. Or, change to `COLUMN(A1:1)` if you want to go to the end of the sheet.

*Credit to pnuts for the INDIRECT idea. :)*